# Mongoose query with formula including 2 columns, Latitude and Longitude, in Node js

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection `users` which contains two fields: latitude and longitude.

I am making a node js request which contain current latitude and current longitude.

I need to make a query that will calculate Haversine Formula and return results within 5 km.

Is there anyone who can help me write this query using mongoose in node js

Comment: you will have to make your calculations before querying the database

Comment: i guess you are trying to say after? Because the latitude and longitude for user will come after the query.

Comment: And one more thing. What if there are thousands of users and we need to find the distance of all users from current latitude and longitude. Is it will be slow with a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried computing it manually, but mongoose has some inbuilt functions to get the points that are close to other points so maybe this helps someone.

You can use the [geojson](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html) data format to store your coordinates in MongoDb, then query using [$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/). It accepts a distance in meters for the `$maxDistance` parameter, so you can do something like:

```
Model.find({
  location: {
    $near: {
      $maxDistance: distanceMeters,
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: coordinates // your reference coordinates as [longitude, latitude],
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Bonus: You can index the `location` field for faster lookups :)